# Swapping elements in ListView does not update model

Tags: java, ajax, wicket-6

I want to change the position of elements in a list. But whenever I swap two elements the model seems to be not updated and the DAO.update doesn't make the update I expect.

Samples in database table (before):

```
 ----------------------
| ID | NAME | POSITION |
 ----------------------
|1194| x    | 1        |
|1195| y    | 2        |
|1196| z    | 3        |
 ----------------------
```

Samples in database table (swap after submit form):

left: wrong, as my codes does;
right: what I expect/need (name and id are unchanged)

```
 ----------------------    ----------------------
| ID | NAME | POSITION |  | ID | NAME | POSITION |
 ----------------------    ----------------------
|1194| y    | 1        |  |1194| x    | 2        |
|1195| x    | 2        |  |1195| y    | 1        |
|1196| z    | 3        |  |1196| z    | 3        |
 ----------------------    ----------------------
```

I have overridden moveDownLink from ListView and added an AJAX call to the end.

Part of my ChangableListView (extends ListView):

```
public final AjaxSubmitLink moveDownLink(final String id, final ListItem<T> item, Form form) {

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
        final int index = getList().indexOf(item.getModelObject());
        if (index != -1) {
            addStateChange();

            Collections.swap(getList(), index, index + 1);
            ChangableListView.this.removeAll();
        }
        target.add(form);
    }
}
```

Use of moveDownLink within ListView and ListView in Form:

```
final ListView<MyType> groupView = new ChangableListView<MyType>("groups", groupModel = new MyTypeListModel()) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final ListItem<MyType> item) {
       item.setModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<MyType>(item.getModel()));

       AjaxSubmitLink downLink = moveDownLink("moveDown", item, form);
       item.add(downLink.isEnabled() ? downLink : new Label("moveDown", ""));

       item.add(new Label("name"));                            
    }
};
form.add(groupView);
```

Hint: MyTypeListModel extends LoadableDetachableModel (LDM) and overrides its load() signature. All entries are correctly loaded and attached to LDM.

Part of Updating in Form.onSubmit():

```
for (int i = 0; i < ((List<MyType>) groupModel.getObject()).size(); i++) {
     MyType group = ((List<MyType>) groupModel.getObject()).get(i);
     // set new order
     group.setHPosition(i + 1);

     dao.update(group);
}
```

**Problem**: After call of moveDownLink/onSubmit(), groupModel.getObject() seems to hold the original values from LDM.load() and not the swapped order from elements with "1194" and "1195".

Comment: Within your `onSubmit` you make 2 calls to `getList()`. Can you include that code or give more detail about is happening within that `getList()` call?

Comment: goes directly to Wickets ListView class

`public final List<? extends T> getList()
 {
  final List<? extends T> list = (List<? extends T>)getDefaultModelObject();
  if (list == null)
  {
   return Collections.emptyList();
  }
  return list;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You say your List is loaded from a LoadableDetachableModel.
It seems to me that you are swapping the items of the query result, but you do not update the DB, so the next time Wicket renders the ListView it makes a new call to the DB and (re)loads the old state.